# JQGrid & Search Engine Indexing

Tags: javascript, jqgrid, seo

I have a mvc3 web application which uses jqgrid extensively. I just came to know that client side grids are not SEO friendly. Search Engines dont index JQGrid data as its client side grid. Is there any way to tweak JQGrid so that it becomes SEO friendly?

I dont want to change dozens of JQGrids with some other server side grid. Please help me in this regard.

Comment: Whats the quick & easy solution to replace JQgrid with some server side Grid that works well with asp.net MVC 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[jqGrid](http://www.trirand.com/blog) is a JavaScript library, and as we all know, search engines are not executing JavaScript. Not to mention that you are probably using AJAX to fetch data from server.

I'm sorry to tell that but in order to make your web page SEO-friendly you need to create JavaScript-free version displaying the same data. Obviously when user enters that page by accident he should be redirected to JavaScript version.